# About Sturm's bound

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

The next theorem is known as Sturm's bound.

**Theorem**:Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a prime ideal in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}$ of a number field $K$, and let  $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup of  of index $m$ and level $N$. Suppose $f\in M_k(\Gamma,\mathcal{O})$ is a modular form and
\begin{align}
\mathrm{ord}_{\mathfrak{m}}(f)>\dfrac{km}{2}.
\end{align}
Then $f\equiv 0\;(\mathrm{mod}\,\mathfrak{m})$.

I want to know if all the sophisticated techniques that Sturm uses in his proof are necessary? In other words, is there a elementary proof? I found, in the case of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$, a sketch of a proof in a book (*Problems In The Theory of modular forms* by M. Ram Murty ) but i can't realize a complete proof. 
Especifically, I'm struggling with the width of cusps, why the existence of a represent of a coset associated to a cusp with $h$ as the value of the width implies the existence of other $h-1$ representatives with the same value of width.